# Ruby on Rails: subdomain too powerful? how do I set this up the right way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

routes:

```
  match '/' => 'site_admin/admin#index'


  resources :link_pages
  resources :services  
  resource :user_session
  resource :account, :controller => "users"
  resources :password_resets
  resources :users
  resources :addresses
  resources :info

  match "/home", :to => 'info#home'
  match "/register", :to => 'users#new'

  root :to => 'info#home'


  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

so when I got to admin.lvh.me:3000/ it goes to site_admin/admin#index... which is great...
but when I take off the subdomain, and just have lvh.me:3000/ it goes to the same route....

how do I get admin to stay where it is. and no subdomain to go to my root page, as in my routes file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes are parsed in order, so when you request / from any domain it finds "match '/'..." first and sends you to the specified page. Your subdomain isn't coming into play at all. You can use Request-based constraints to route based on subdomain:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how subdomain factors into this at all. Perhaps you're confusing subdomain with route namespacing (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)?

```
match '/' => 'site_admin/admin#index'
```

Is being selected over

```
root :to => 'info#home'
```

Because it's defined first in the routes file. They're ostensibly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Cory is right. Above both statements are similar and first defined route is considered every time. If you change admin route to

```
match '/admin' => 'site_admin/admin#index'
```

then it does make sense... What say??

or else, using the following code you can determine your URL conditionally:

```
request.subdomains(0).first
```

will give you the subdomain value- either admin or blank. But it will go to any one controller action only which is defined first in route.rb file.

Then from that action using subdomain, you can decide where to re-direct it- either to admin panel or home page...